# css and js file changes after page reload

Tags: html, css, file, deployment, web-hosting

I am having this project, where I am developing an online game with my team.
You can play it here: [sta.schranz.io](http://sta.schranz.io)

On the first load you can see that the border is colorful. If you reload, the border is invisible. I found out that the file names change after the reload. **From style.css** and bundle.js **to style.css.pageload.[random character].css**.

Do you know what this means and how it can be undone?

Comment: For me it had random name in first visit. You may see style.css from a cache

Comment: It isn't the file, I was looking at your css code, and there is an error about var(--borderWidth) It says unsupported property value, You declared it in lowercase and that is why the value does not exist

Comment: Thank you both. I could fix the problem with the border. But do you know where these strange names come from?

Comment: I am NOT too expert but it's up to apache server (I could see you are using it, maybe I am wrong), that is how it manages your files.

Comment: I found the reason for these additional characters. You were right, thank you. There is a setting in my server preferences for mod_pagespeed (some google technology) It was on.

Comment: @maadc We both learnt together something new. Ty